Where does Conjugate base [A-] concentration come from in HA dissocation that is used in derivation of kb*ka=kw?
Suppose in reaction: $\ce{HA +H2O <=> H3O+ + A-}$
$K_\text{a}=\dfrac{[\ce{H3O+}][\ce{A-}]}{[\ce{HA}]}$
And then conjugate base $\ce{A-}$ reacts with $\ce{H2O}$
$$\ce{A- + H2O <=> HA + OH-}$$
In this reaction the conjugate base $[\ce{A-}]$ was present before or it came from the dissoaction of $\ce{HA}$?

Review the search results site:stackexchange.com  OR site:libretexts.org acid base conjugate pair dissociation constant Ka Kb Kw.

A- was either present either was formed by HA dissociation.  Kb=Kw/Ka = [HA][OH-]/[A-] is valid for A- of any origin.

Reactions
\begin{align}
\ce{HA +H2O &<=> A- + H3O+} &K_\text{a}=\dfrac{[\ce{H3O+}][\ce{A-}]}{[\ce{HA}]}\tag{1}\\
\ce{A- + H2O &<=> HA + OH-} &K_\text{b}=\frac{K_\text{w}}{K_\text{a}}=\dfrac{[\ce{HA}][\ce{OH-}]}{[\ce{A-}]}\tag{2}
\end{align}
can be for easier understanding rewritten as two ways of writing two parallel equilibrium reactions:
\begin{align}
\ce{HA +H2O &<=> H3O+ + A-} &K=K_\text{a}\tag{3}\\
\ce{HA + OH- &<=> A- + H2O} &K=\frac{K_\text{a}}{K_\text{w}}\tag{4}
\end{align}
OR
\begin{align}
\ce{A- + H3O+ &<=> HA +H2O} &K= \frac{1}{K_\text{a}}\tag{5}\\
\ce{A- + H2O &<=> HA + OH-} &K=\frac{K_\text{w}}{K_\text{a}}\tag{6}
\end{align}
Note that $K_\text{w} =  [\ce{H3O+}][\ce{OH-}]\tag{7}$
The origin of the $\ce{A-}$ does not matter, only its presence:

If acetic acid is dissolved in water, all acetate comes from acid dissociation.
If sodium acetate is dissolved in water, all original acetate was already present.
If mixture of acetic acid and sodium acetate is dissolved in water, acetate come from both the acetate salt and dissociation of acetic acid.

As there is ongoing fast bidirectional acid dissociation and association reactions, more and more acetate comes from dissociation and is consumed by association.
